# Nightmarejs with cheerio selector returning all DOM instead of selected element

Tags: node.js, cheerio, nightmare

Been having some issue pairing nightmarejs with cheerio. 
Trying to pass the resulting document.body.innerHTML from the evaluate to cheerio like so

```
           ...
var title = yield nightmare.goto(urls[i])
                .wait('.result-title')            
                .evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML)
                .then(function (html) {
                    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
                   ...
```

However after calling console.log($('.address-text')); I'm presented with a never-ending DOM structure. It's been going like this for quite some time as seen in this screenshot

[image]

Comment: first can you just end it after evaluate `evaluate(fn).end().then(fn)`? then copy the html and check the html content for the class '.address-text'? that will give you hints to debug.

Comment: Hello , thanks . I managed to reduce the scope by only looking for what I need with  .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.location-meta-block').innerHTML) . then $('.address-text').text() returns what I need.